# To find sum of infinite series.

Tags: sequences-and-series

How to find the sum of the following infinite series?

$$\frac1{2 \cdot 3 \cdot 4}+\frac1{4 \cdot 5 \cdot 6}+\frac1{6 \cdot 7 \cdot 8}+\cdots$$

I can write its partial sum but am unable to proceed.

Comment: Multiplication is something different from the end of sentence, and so it has its own symbol, different from a full stop aka period. You can obtain it with the LaTeX command `\cdot`, like in `2 \cdot 3` which is rendered as $2 \cdot 3$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac1{(n-1)n(n+1)}=\frac12\left(\frac1{n-1}-\frac2n+\frac1{n+1}\right)$$
so your sum is
$$\frac12\left(\frac12-\frac23+\frac24-\frac25+\frac26-\frac27+\cdots\right).$$
This is very similar to
$$\frac11-\frac12+\frac13-\frac14+\cdots.$$